# Android App crashed after some time

Tags: java, android, timer

I've a problem which I do not have a clue on what causing the crash. I have a inner class of Timer which is triggered from the `MainActivity` `onCreate()` every minute.

```
timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(),2000, 10000);
```

This is my Timer class.This timer class responsible in start another activity.

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

public CaptureActivityHandler cah = new CaptureActivityHandler();
public void run() {
    Log.d("TIMER",  "timer is triggered");
    TimerCount++;

    if(TimerCount > 1)
    {
        Log.d("TIMER",  "TimerCount > 1");
        boolean flag = cah.getDecodeFlag();

        if(flag){
            Log.d("TIMER",  "decodeFlag true");
            cah.setDecodeFlag(false);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,SCAN_QRCODE_REQUEST);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,SCAN_QRCODE_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,SCAN_QRCODE_REQUEST);
    }
   }
}
```

The problem is the app crashed after 15 hours. Logcat showing:

```
01-21 11:01:42.027: W/dalvikvm(30401): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x41ddd930)
01-21 11:01:42.027: W/ActivityManager(363): Unable to find app for caller   android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4275bf18 (pid=-1) when starting: Intent {  cmp=com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/tw.com.quickmark.sdk.CaptureActivity }
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401): java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent { cmp=com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/tw.com.quickmark.sdk.CaptureActivity }
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1625)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk.MainActivity$RemindTask.run(MainActivity.java:562)
01-21 11:01:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(30401):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
01-21 11:01:42.037: W/ActivityManager(363): Can't find mystery application for Crash from pid=30401 uid=10079: android.os.BinderProxy@42976028
01-21 11:01:42.037: I/Process(30401): Sending signal. PID: 30401 SIG: 9
01-21 11:01:42.147: W/InputDispatcher(363): channel '42600fd8 com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-21 11:01:42.147: E/InputDispatcher(363): channel '42600fd8 com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-21 11:01:42.147: W/InputDispatcher(363): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42600fd8 com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk.MainActivity (server)'
01-21 11:01:42.147: I/WindowState(363): WIN DEATH: Window{42600fd8 u0 com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk.MainActivity}
```

Then having the thought it may caused by memory leak, then I shorten the timer period to 10secs. As expected, it crashed after 2.5 hours.

However, It's seems unlikely is because of the memory because the used heap size is always about 58%. Besides, the memory usage is about 4% which is 35M out of total 100% of device memory.

Here is the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="tw.com.quickmark.sdk.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="tw.com.quickmark.sdk.PreferencesActivity" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.test.MySpiceService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Any thought of what might cause the crashing?

Comment: Can you post your CaptureActivity.java

Comment: if u have startActivityforresult for each case then why scheduleAtFixedRate , use new Timer().schedule(task, after) instead.

Comment: Thanks Manmohan. Purpose of scheduleAtFixedRate is to start the CaptureActivity repeatedly to test whether the app will crash if it go to CaptureActivity repeatedly.

Comment: Hai Clay, CaptureActivity is more or less the same as https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java

Comment: @jwgan have you added all your activities into your manifest? Care to post that?

Comment: @Clay Ya.I have added all activities.

Comment: @jwgan Is captureactivity.java in your src folder or are u refering to it from a library?

Comment: @jwgan Actually, can you please try this, it might work. Change **MainActivity.this** to **getApplicationContext()**

Comment: Sorry @Clay for the late reply.  captureActivity.java is refering from a library. And I found that the process of this app is not get killed because I still can see the process is running at DDMS. It's just doesn't show on foreground.

Comment: @Clay I tested with getApplicationContext(). not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer but you should change your `run()` method to this...

```
public void run() {
    Log.d("TIMER",  "timer is triggered");
    TimerCount++;

    if (TimerCount > 1) {
        Log.d("TIMER",  "TimerCount > 1");
        boolean flag = cah.getDecodeFlag();

        if(flag){
            Log.d("TIMER",  "decodeFlag true");
            cah.setDecodeFlag(false);
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,SCAN_QRCODE_REQUEST);

}
```

It does the exact same thing except with less repetition.

Answer (score 0):

The exception showed "java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent { cmp=com.handalindah.manjalinkkiosk/tw.com.quickmark.sdk.CaptureActivity }".

tw.com.quickmark.sdk.CaptureActivity is unregistered after certain running?